# Fit algorithm does not accept my data

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

I'm using the algorithm described [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData) to fit Gaussian bell curves to my data.

If I generate my data array with:

```
x=linspace(1.,100.,100)
data= 17*exp(-((x-10)/3)**2)
```

everything works fine.

But if I read the data from a text file using

```
file = open("d:\\test7.txt")
arr=[]
data=[]


def column(matrix,i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]

for line in file.readlines():
    numbers=map(float, line.split())
    arr.append(numbers)
    
data = column(arr,300)
x=linspace(1.,115.,115)
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "readmatrix.py", line 60, in <module>    fit(f, [mu, sigma, height], data)
File "readmatrix.py", line 42, in fit    if x is None: x = arange(y.shape[0])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

As far as I can see, the values included in data are correct, it looks like:

```
[0.108032, 0.86181600000000003, 1.386169, 3.2790530000000002, ... ]
```

Has someone a clue what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @Dzz: you aren't even including the relevant portions of your source code.  Line 42 is where your error occurs because you are using "y.shape[0]" and y is a list type that doesn't have a shape attribute.  You're going to need to include more source for us to properly find the error.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping to reduce the amount of text in the post by linking to the code.

Answer (score 4):

The fit function expects the data as a numpy Array (which has a shape attribute) and not a list (which does not), hence the AttributeError.

Convert your data:

```
def column(matrix,i):
    return numpy.asarray([row[i] for row in matrix])
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution of balpha is not correct; the solution is simply to convert my list to a numpy array via numpy.array.

Thanks for giving me a hint!

Comment: In what way is it not correct? (I just used the numpy documentation, according to which asarray should work; I don't have numpy installed) What error are you getting?

Comment: It does, but the command arr.append(numbers) makes again a list out of the numpy.array..

Comment: arr.append(numbers) is called *before* column(), so that shouldn't make a difference. Anyway, as long as it works... :-)